# can I depict opcodes in inline assembly? (GNU or OSX)

Tags: macos, assembly, window, opcode, emit

I have to translate windows assembly with `__emit` directive & opcode and transform it as OSX assembly. The original code look like,

```
__asm { 
test:
       __emit 0x0008
.
.
.
}
```

(`0x0008` means nothing, just example)

I'm wondering, is there any equivalent directive in gnu or osx compiler(`llvm`) with `__emit` directive which is execute opcode directly.

any advice is welcome. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The GCC equivalent of __emit is:

```
.long 0xXXXXXXXX
.short 0xXXXX
.byte 0xXX
```

depending on the size (32, 16 or 8 bits) of the data inserted.